# Why can't I move apps from internal storage to SD card on my new Android 7.1.1 device?

Tags: external-sd

Just bought the Moto E4 Plus. Installed a 64gb SD card to hold all my apps so they don't hold most of my 32gb of internal storage. I'm running Android 7.1.1 and I can't move any apps to the SD card. Even ones that I was able to in previous Android versions. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be because of manufacturer-integrated changes - some manufacturers like to disable Android features of their choice like does Xiaomi in their MIUI, for example.

Comment: is there any way to re-enable these features? with or without root?

Comment: Maybe enabling adoptable storage will help. Do you have it enabled right now?

Comment: no, nor do I know how to check. a lot of Android is new to me as I haven't played with it as much as I'd like to have.

Comment: Or you can use app like Folder Mount (utilizes root access) to bind your apps data directories from built-in phone storage to your SD card (only data, not apps themself).

Comment: i need a way to move the apps entirely. I'd prefer to have the app backed up as a while instead of just their data.

Comment: You can check adoptable storage state and availability by navigating into "Settings" - "Storage & USB" - your SD Card & pressing menu button. If in menu window that appears after "format as internal" option available - then you can format your SD card as adoptable, if "format as external" or something similar available instead - then "adoptable storage" on your phone is already activated and if there is no such options available... Then your phone doesn't support adoptable storage at all. But there is still ways to activate it, if you interested.